# ASP.Net MVC Rotative ActionAsPdf doesn't redirect to my inner action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, rotativa

I am using **Rotative** to export specific view as PDF page and i am using this code but when it enters in "***ExportPDF***" it never get into ***ConfirmPDFReport*** and i used the same code in another project and it works well.

```
public ActionResult ExportPDF(string orderId)
        {
            try
            {


                return new ActionAsPdf("ConfirmPDFReport", new {orderId = orderId })
                {
                    FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString() + "FlightTicketInfo.pdf"
                ,
                    PageOrientation = Orientation.Landscape
                ,
                    MinimumFontSize = 18
                };
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("GeneralError", "Error", new { ErrorMessage = e.Message });
            }

        }


public ActionResult ConfirmPDFReport(string orderId)
    {

        try
        {

            return View("ConfirmationPDF", FlightSearchSession);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("GeneralError", "Error", new { ErrorMessage = e.Message, parameter = "OrderId=" + orderId });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> try like this, it will be work

```
public ActionResult ExportPDF(string orderId)
    {
        try
        {
            return View("ConfirmPDFReport", new {orderId = orderId });

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("GeneralError", "Error", new { ErrorMessage = e.Message });
        }

    }

 public ActionResult ConfirmPDFReport(string orderId)
{

    try
    {

        return new ActionAsPdf("ConfirmationPDF", FlightSearchSession) 
       {
                FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString() + "FlightTicketInfo.pdf"
            ,
                PageOrientation = Orientation.Landscape
            ,
                MinimumFontSize = 18
            };
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("GeneralError", "Error", new { ErrorMessage = e.Message, parameter = "OrderId=" + orderId });
    }
}
```